# Prove that $\frac{\pi(2x)\text{log}\, x}{x}$ has a constant upper bound.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

I know that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\pi(2x)\text{log}(x)}{x} = \sum_{p < 2x} \frac{\text{log} \, x}{x},
\end{equation*}
but other than that I'm not sure how to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with Chebyshev's bounds for the prime counting function?

Comment: @Gary Is that the theorem $\exists s_{1},s_{2}, s_{1} \frac{x}{\text{log}\, x} < \pi(x) < s_{2} \frac{x}{\text{log}\, x}$?

Comment: @Peter Why would $\frac{\text{log} \, x}{x}$ turn into $\frac{\text{log} \, p}{p}$?

Comment: @Peter: No, then it would be wrong. It just counts the primes up to $2x$ times the constant $\frac{\log x}x$. Unusual but correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x\geq 2$. By Chebyshev's result, there is a $c>0$ such that
$$
\pi (2x) < c\frac{{2x}}{{\log (2x)}} = 2c\frac{x}{{\log x + \log 2}} <2c\frac{x}{{\log x}} ,
$$
whence
$$
\frac{{\pi (2x)\log x}}{x} < 2c.
$$
Obviously this result extends to $x>0$.

Comment: Which $c$ can we choose such that the inequality holds for all $x>1$ ?

Comment: @Peter $\pi(2x) \log x /x<4$ certainly holds for all $x>0$.

Comment: For $x\le 1$ , the given expression is $0$, so the interesting part is the case $x>1$

Comment: @Peter Yes, I am aware of that. Numerically it seems that the best possible upper bound for $\pi(2x) \log x /x$ is somewhat above $2$.